# EF Core Spatial Data Distance

Tags: spatialite, ef-core-2.2

Using ef core 2.2 spatial data with Sqlite. When trying to do a query that returns all known location in {x} radius the input wants degrees and not meters.

```
var nearByLocations = _context.Locations.Where(x => x.Location.Distance(current.Location) <= 0.1666666).ToList();
```

I thought if the query was on the server side it would comeback in meters? I'm guessing Sqlite just isn't considered a server. I can confirm same results in a query using spatialite_gui

```
select Distance(Location, (SELECT Location FROM Facility WHERE 
LocationIdentifier = '123')) as distance
from Facility
where LocationIdentifier = '456' --distance: 0.336804
```

So is this a limitation? If so what would be best way to find location in meters?

EDIT

I was able to accomplish what I wanted via RAW SQL query. First I used function "PtDistWithin" then I did an order by Distance. With Distance function I had to transformed it another SRID.

Wish I was able to query via Linq but this works too.

```
var nearBy = _context.Facilities.FromSql(
                    "SELECT * FROM Facility WHERE FacilityType = 'Test' AND " +
                    "PtDistWithin(Location, {0}, CvtFromKmi({1})) " +
                    "ORDER BY Distance(TRANSFORM(Location,2855), TRANSFORM({2},2855));", bus.Location, 20, bus.Location).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey, how did you set up your project in order to make it work with NetTopologySuit? I am actually facing issues with SQLite as it is not being able to find sqlite3.dll dependency

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning this stuff myself, but I think that Distance as returned by EF Core with NetTopologySuite (the spatial provider for EF Core) just does a cartesian distance (i.e. returns the same units as the coordinates. This is because the underlying type is geometry and not geography.  This appears to differ from the in built ST_Distance function in sql server which does return metres. However this is only true if you use the geography datatype...